# Como realizar a paralelização deste trecho de código usando OpenMp

Tags: c++, openmp

estou tentando paralelizar uma atividade utilizando `OpenMp`. Eu tendo problemas pois após o primeiro for do código abaixo o resultado se mostra errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countLines(ifstream &file) {

    int count = 0;

    for (string line; getline(file, line); ) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

float maxErrorCriteria(float *array, int arraySize) {

    float max = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        #pragma omp critical
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

void invertSignal(float *array) {
    *array == 0 ? 0 : *array *= -1;
}

int arrayPosition(int line, int column, int columnCount) {
    return (((line) * (columnCount)) + column);
}

void alocateArray(float **array, int size) {
    *array = new float[size];
}

void cleanArray(float *array, int size) {
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    ifstream file;
    int matrixSize = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    float *variableArray;
    float *constantArray;
    float *errorArray;
    float *errorArrayAux;
    float const STOP_CRITERIA = 0.001;
    string filename = "matriz.txt";

    // abrindo o arquivo
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    // buscando o numero de linhas
    row = countLines(file);

    // criando vetor dos valores das constantes 1 / diagonal principal
    alocateArray(&constantArray, row);
    cleanArray(constantArray, row);

    // calculando o tamanho da matriz
    column = row + 1;
    matrixSize = row * column;

    // criando vetor valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&variableArray, matrixSize);
    cleanArray(variableArray, matrixSize);

    // reposicionando o arquivo no inicio
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);

    // populando o vetor de variveis
    #pragma omp parallel shared(i, j, pos, variableArray)
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            file >> variableArray[pos];         
        }
    }

    pos = 0;
    // populando o vetor de constantes
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, pos) shared(constantArray, variableArray)
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        pos = arrayPosition(i, i, column);
        constantArray[i] = (1 / variableArray[pos]);
        variableArray[pos] = 0;
    }

    // invertendo o sinal
    #pragma omp parallel for private (i, j, pos) shared(variableArray)
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (column - 1); j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            invertSignal(&variableArray[pos]);
        }
    }

    // fechado o arquivo
    file.close();

    // criando vetor da margem de erro valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&errorArray, row);
    cleanArray(errorArray, row);

    // criando vetor auxiliar da margem de erro valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&errorArrayAux, row);
    cleanArray(errorArrayAux, row);

    float higherCriteria = 0;

    do {

        for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < (column - 1); j++) {
                pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
                errorArrayAux[i] += variableArray[pos] * errorArray[j];
            }

            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            errorArrayAux[i] += variableArray[pos];
            errorArrayAux[i] *= constantArray[i];

        }

        // copiando os valores
        memcpy(errorArray, errorArrayAux, row * sizeof(float));

        // localizando o maior
        higherCriteria = maxErrorCriteria(errorArray, row);

        for(int cu = 0; cu < row; cu++) {
            cout << "x"<< (cu+1) << " " << errorArrayAux[cu] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        // limpando o vetor
        cleanArray(errorArrayAux, row);

    } while(STOP_CRITERIA > (1 - higherCriteria));


    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            cout << variableArray[pos] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

O processo é o seguinte, no primeiro `for` eu populo o `array` com conteúdo de um arquivo, ele funciona corretamente, no segundo for seria para separar o valores da diagonal principal para um segundo array e zerar o valores. E no terceiro sera inverter os valores que estão na ultima coluna deste vetor.

A função `arrayPosition` retorna o valor da posição do array em função dos 2 for que simulam ele como uma matriz.

Venho usando o `Visual Studio 2012`.

Comment: "funciona corretamente". O conteúdo da array é o mesmo conteúdo do arquivo? Você checou isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, sim, esta correto, no primeiro for.

Comment: Por que motivo `i` e `j` são `shared` no último ciclo?

Comment: @luiscubal eu esqueci de arrumar essa parte, pois ela esta comentada, na verdade os 2 são `privates`. Mas o erro já começa no segundo `for`

Comment: Tem como postar a função `arrayPosition` e como foi declarado o array `variableArray`?

Comment: @TomásBadan postei o código inteiro!

Answer (score 1):

O código corrigido seria este, lembrando que eu tirei a inicialização das variáveis que estão nas clausulas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int arrayPosition(int line, int column, int columnCount) {
    return (((line) * (columnCount)) + column);
}

int countLines(ifstream &file) {

    int count = 0;

    for (string line; getline(file, line); ) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

float maxErrorCriteria(float *array, int arraySize) {

    float max = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        #pragma omp critical
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

void invertSignal(float *array) {
    *array == 0 ? 0 : *array *= -1;
}

void alocateArray(float **array, int size) {
    *array = new float[size];
}

void cleanArray(float *array, int size) {
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    ifstream file;
    int matrixSize;
    int row;
    int column;
    int i;
    int j;
    int pos;
    float *variableArray;
    float *constantArray;
    float *errorArray;
    float *errorArrayAux;
    float const STOP_CRITERIA = 0.001;
    string filename = "matriz.txt";

    // abrindo o arquivo
    file.open(filename.c_str());

    // buscando o numero de linhas
    row = countLines(file);

    // criando vetor dos valores das constantes 1 / diagonal principal
    alocateArray(&constantArray, row);
    cleanArray(constantArray, row);

    // calculando o tamanho da matriz
    column = row + 1;
    matrixSize = row * column;

    // criando vetor valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&variableArray, matrixSize);
    cleanArray(variableArray, matrixSize);

    // reposicionando o arquivo no inicio
    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);

    // populando o vetor de variveis
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(variableArray)
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            file >> variableArray[pos];         
        }
    }

    // populando o vetor de constantes
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(constantArray, variableArray)
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        pos = arrayPosition(i, i, column);
        constantArray[i] = (1 / variableArray[pos]);
        variableArray[pos] = 0;
    }

    // invertendo o sinal
    #pragma omp parallel for private (i, j) shared(variableArray)
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < (column - 1); j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            invertSignal(&variableArray[pos]);
        }
    }

    // fechado o arquivo
    file.close();

    // criando vetor da margem de erro valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&errorArray, row);
    cleanArray(errorArray, row);

    // criando vetor auxiliar da margem de erro valores da matriz
    alocateArray(&errorArrayAux, row);
    cleanArray(errorArrayAux, row);

    float higherCriteria = 0;

    do {

        for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < (column - 1); j++) {
                pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
                errorArrayAux[i] += variableArray[pos] * errorArray[j];
            }

            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            errorArrayAux[i] += variableArray[pos];
            errorArrayAux[i] *= constantArray[i];

        }

        // copiando os valores
        memcpy(errorArray, errorArrayAux, row * sizeof(float));

        // localizando o maior
        higherCriteria = maxErrorCriteria(errorArray, row);

        for(int cu = 0; cu < row; cu++) {
            cout << "x"<< (cu+1) << " " << errorArrayAux[cu] << "\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";

        // limpando o vetor
        cleanArray(errorArrayAux, row);

    } while(STOP_CRITERIA > (1 - higherCriteria));


    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            pos = arrayPosition(i, j, column);
            cout << variableArray[pos] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Pode evidenciar o que estava causando o problema?

Comment: Iniciando o valor das variáveis no trecho do `for`. Por exemplo `i` e `j`.